# Replacement for Google Desktop

Tags: hotkeys, google-desktop-search

Although Google Desktop was discontinued long ago, I kept the installer and was able to continue to use it. The functionality that I used the most was "hit Ctrl twice and bring up a Google search". This is not "bring up Google.com in the browser" but it is a search box that appears on top of whatever windows I have open, and after typing the query and hitting Enter it directs me to Google.com with the search results displayed.

I still have it installed, but somehow the Ctrl-Ctrl hotkey stopped working. (Maybe because of a Windows update.) What I'm looking for is

- Repair the hotkey if possible; what may have turned it off and how to restore previous behaviour
- Or else: software offering similar functionality

Of course if neither is possible, I may set up AutoHotkey or something to associate Ctrl-Ctrl with Google.com.

(I don't need the Desktop Search functionality, only Web Search.)

Comment: This is known as the old google quicksearch box. The best way to get it is from the I.E. google search bar. Is there a `Google` button beside your start button on your taskbar?

Comment: @DarthAndroid Nope. I'm on Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: Oh sorry, asked too early. Restarting GD fixed the hotkey. Should I close the question now?

Comment: You could also post that as an answer and accept it (i.e., "Restarting Google desktop reregistered the hotkey.") That way, others experiencing the same issue will find your answer!

Comment: I wrote a version in Python: https://gist.github.com/marczellm/9bb3a39c14fdf5a28c47ff132307aff6

Comment: How is this offtopic? he is asking about a specific program that was once often used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exiting and restarting Google Desktop should restore the hotkey.

(Note that this hotkey does not always bring up the search box, such as when running a browser in fullscreen mode.)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a hotkey to directly start your browser, then search directly from there; usually most keyboards and laptops have a dedicated "home page" launcher key that serve this purpose.
That's kind of a workaround, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the hotkey with restarting Google Desktop. This would fix your prob. Btw. I think the performance is a little bit low. This is why I use third party software to replace Google Desktop as [Windows Search](http://lookeen.com) solution. I know this is a little bit expensive but to me it is worth. With the performance of the web search there's no trouble at all. I'm fine with it

Comment: This duplicates the accepted answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: @DavidPostill This answer contributes something new, namely a recommendation for a software replicating the functionality of Google Desktop, which was the second part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be the free or paid tool [Lookeen](http://free.lookeen.com). The free version offers all features of the paid version but only indexes drive C: . Another nice feature you may like is the the start on double ctrl tap ;).